# ORA2 xblock customization

Tags: python, openedx

I am python-django developer , recently I have been assigned with a task to customize ora2 xblock in openedx . The customization includes adding some tables in ora xblock and making some api that can be consumed externally . So after a long struggle I managed to find the code of ora at 
/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openassessment/

Now here in models file I have added some custom model  , but I have no idea how to migrate it as I don't see any manage.py file also I connot find any view.py file either through which I can link my custom api url and through which I can pass data to django template .

I really need help as I am lost in ocean of openedx :/

Comment: For this, you can develop ORA2 separately, as an xblock (see xbloack SDK).  Here is the ORA2 repo https://github.com/edx/edx-ora2

Comment: But where should I clone it ? Separately ? And where do I run it in the existing system in order  test it ?